# How to use arrow functions inside React.createClass

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I want to use ES6 (ES2015) as much as possible for my small project. Now I want to use arrow functions with React.

```
// What I want
let Text = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount: () => {
        setInterval(this.updateCurrentTime, 1000);
    }
}

// What I have
let Paragraph = React.createClass({
    render: () => (<div className="MySuperTable"><Text name="Dodo" startDate={(new Date()).toString()} /></div>)
});

let Text = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            currentTime: (new Date()).toString()
        }
    },
    componentDidMount: function () {
        setInterval(this.updateCurrentTime, 1000);
    },
    updateCurrentTime: function () {
        this.setState({
            currentTime: (new Date()).toString()
        });
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>
                <span>Hello my name is {this.props.name}</span>
                <span>And I was born on {this.props.startDate}</span>
                <span>And I now it's {this.state.currentTime}</span>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(
    <Paragraph/>,
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```

1. What do I have to do to get this working?
2. As I understand `this` will be the object passed into `createClass` itself, is this correct?
3. How do I bind it to the `Text` instance?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Arrow function vs function declaration / expressions: Are they equivalent / exchangeable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/arrow-function-vs-function-declaration-expressions-are-they-equivalent-exch)

Comment: You cannot simply replace normal functions with arrow functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change your code with `ES2015` like this

```
class Text extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { currentTime: (new Date()).toString() };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    setInterval(() => this.updateCurrentTime(), 1000);
  }

  updateCurrentTime() {
    this.setState({
      currentTime: (new Date()).toString()
    });
  }

  render() {
    return <div>
      <span>Hello my name is { this.props.name }</span>
      <span>And i was born { this.props.startDate }</span>
      <span>And i now it's { this.state.currentTime }</span>
    </div>  
  }
};

let Paragraph = () => {
  return <div className="MySuperTable">
    <Text name="Dodo" startDate={ (new Date()).toString() } />
  </div>
};
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/35183/)

[`React - Reusable Components`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html)

Answer (score 1):

As you said, you wanted use ES6 as much as possible. So then instead of using createClass, you can use 'React.Component', you can find more info [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/01/27/react-v0.13.0-beta-1.html).

And then to use, arrow mark you can use Babel, preset-2015.

Comment: Thanks, i have just marked right answer, but yours seems to be good as well.